# Calculating sum of up to the current row in pandas while iterating on each row in a time series data

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

Suppose I have the following code that calculates how many products I can purchase given my budget-

```
import math
import pandas as pd

data = [['2021-01-02', 5.5], ['2021-02-02', 10.5], ['2021-03-02', 15.0], ['2021-04-02', 20.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Current_Price'])

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
mn = df.Date.min()
mx = df.Date.max()
dr = pd.date_range(mn - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(), mx + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(), name="Date")
df = df.set_index("Date").reindex(dr).reset_index()
df['Current_Price'] = df.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M'))['Current_Price'].ffill().bfill()

# The dataframe below shows the current price of the product
# I'd like to buy at the specific date_range
print(df)

# Create 'Day' column to know which day of the month
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.day

# Create 'Deposit' column to record how much money is
# deposited in, say, my bank account to buy the product.
# 'Withdrawal' column is to record how much I spent in
# buying product(s) at the current price on a specific date.
# 'Num_of_Products_Bought' shows how many items I bought
# on that specific date.
#
# Please note that the calculate below takes into account
# the left over money, which remains after I've purchased a 
# product, for future purchase. For example, if you observe 
# the resulting dataframe at the end of this code, you'll 
# notice that I was able to purchase 7 products on March 1, 2021
# although my deposit on that day was $100. That is because 
# on the days leading up to March 1, 2021, I have been saving 
# the spare change from previous product purchases and that 
# extra money allows me to buy an extra product on March 1, 2021 
# despite my budget of $100 should only allow me to purchase 
# 6 products.
df[['Deposit', 'Withdrawal', 'Num_of_Products_Bought']] = 0.0

# Suppose I save $100 at the beginning of every month in my bank account
df.loc[df['Day'] == 1, 'Deposit'] = 100.0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, 'Day'] == 1:
        # num_prod_bought = (sum_of_deposit_so_far - sum_of_withdrawal)/current_price
        df.loc[index, 'Num_of_Products_Bought'] = math.floor(
            (sum(df.iloc[0:(index + 1)]['Deposit'])
             - sum(df.iloc[0:(index + 1)]['Withdrawal']))
            / df.loc[index, 'Current_Price'])
        # Record how much I spent buying the product on specific date
        df.loc[index, 'Withdrawal'] = df.loc[index, 'Num_of_Products_Bought'] * df.loc[index, 'Current_Price']

print(df)
# This code above is working as intended,
# but how can I make it more efficient/pandas-like?
# In particular, I don't like to idea of having to
# iterate the rows and having to recalculate
# the running (sum of) deposit amount and
# the running (sum of) the withdrawal.
```

As mentioned in the comment in the code, I would like to know how to accomplish the same without having to iterate the rows one by one and calculating the sum of the rows up to the current row in my iteration (I read around StackOverflow and saw `cumsum()` function, but I don't think `cumsum` has the notion of current row in the iteration).

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions/answers!

Comment: I'm a little confused as you say your current code is working as intended, but you mention a running sum. Your output currently just has the day==1 rows filled and everything else is 0. Are you looking to expand this over multiple days? Or are you looking for exactly the output that's being produced in a more pandas way?

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, apology if my question wasn't clear. I'm hoping to find a more pandas way to accomplish the same that I got in the above code. Basically, I'm concerned that my code is not efficient as it can be because I am iterating through the rows and for every row, I'm recalculating the sum up to (or before) that row for both `'Deposit'` and `'Withdrawal'`. Hoping that someone would share a pattern, if any, in pandas that can achieve similar. Thank you!

Comment: So line 59 in your implementation says you buy 7 and purchase $105 worth which would put you negative. My implementation produces 6 items for a total of $90. Is it not the case you wanted the total to purchase to be less than the amount you have?

Comment: @HenryEcker I should have been clearer. My implementation bought 7 products (a value of $105) because it is counting the extra change that I have been saving up to that point. In other words, in the days leading up to March 1, 2021, I spent less than the deposit amount and those extra money allows me to purchase one extra product on March 1, 2021. I'll update my question shortly to make this clearer. Is there a way to implement this in pandas without having to iterate row by row and calculate `sum` for every row?

Comment: You could define your own function to apply to each row of the dataframe and then use `df.apply(function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `.apply`:

```py
def fn():
    leftover = 0
    amount, deposit = yield
    while True:
        new_amount, new_deposit = yield (deposit + leftover) // amount
        leftover = (deposit + leftover) % amount
        amount, deposit = new_amount, new_deposit


df = df.set_index("Date")
s = fn()
next(s)
m = df.index.day == 1
df.loc[m, "Deposit"] = 100
df.loc[m, "Num_of_Products_Bought"] = df.loc[
    m, ["Current_Price", "Deposit"]
].apply(lambda x: s.send((x["Current_Price"], x["Deposit"])), axis=1)
df.loc[m, "Withdrawal"] = (
    df.loc[m, "Num_of_Products_Bought"] * df.loc[m, "Current_Price"]
)
print(df.fillna(0).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
          Date  Current_Price  Deposit  Num_of_Products_Bought  Withdrawal
0   2021-01-01            5.5    100.0                    18.0        99.0
1   2021-01-02            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
2   2021-01-03            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
3   2021-01-04            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
4   2021-01-05            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
5   2021-01-06            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
6   2021-01-07            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
7   2021-01-08            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
8   2021-01-09            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
9   2021-01-10            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
10  2021-01-11            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
11  2021-01-12            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
12  2021-01-13            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
13  2021-01-14            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
14  2021-01-15            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
15  2021-01-16            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
16  2021-01-17            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
17  2021-01-18            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
18  2021-01-19            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
19  2021-01-20            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
20  2021-01-21            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
21  2021-01-22            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
22  2021-01-23            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
23  2021-01-24            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
24  2021-01-25            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
25  2021-01-26            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
26  2021-01-27            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
27  2021-01-28            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
28  2021-01-29            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
29  2021-01-30            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
30  2021-01-31            5.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
31  2021-02-01           10.5    100.0                     9.0        94.5
32  2021-02-02           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
33  2021-02-03           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
34  2021-02-04           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
35  2021-02-05           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
36  2021-02-06           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
37  2021-02-07           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
38  2021-02-08           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
39  2021-02-09           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
40  2021-02-10           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
41  2021-02-11           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
42  2021-02-12           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
43  2021-02-13           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
44  2021-02-14           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
45  2021-02-15           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
46  2021-02-16           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
47  2021-02-17           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
48  2021-02-18           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
49  2021-02-19           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
50  2021-02-20           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
51  2021-02-21           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
52  2021-02-22           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
53  2021-02-23           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
54  2021-02-24           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
55  2021-02-25           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
56  2021-02-26           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
57  2021-02-27           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
58  2021-02-28           10.5      0.0                     0.0         0.0
59  2021-03-01           15.0    100.0                     7.0       105.0
60  2021-03-02           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
61  2021-03-03           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
62  2021-03-04           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
63  2021-03-05           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
64  2021-03-06           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
65  2021-03-07           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
66  2021-03-08           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
67  2021-03-09           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
68  2021-03-10           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
69  2021-03-11           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
70  2021-03-12           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
71  2021-03-13           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
72  2021-03-14           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
73  2021-03-15           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
74  2021-03-16           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
75  2021-03-17           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
76  2021-03-18           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
77  2021-03-19           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
78  2021-03-20           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
79  2021-03-21           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
80  2021-03-22           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
81  2021-03-23           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
82  2021-03-24           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
83  2021-03-25           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
84  2021-03-26           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
85  2021-03-27           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
86  2021-03-28           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
87  2021-03-29           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
88  2021-03-30           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
89  2021-03-31           15.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
90  2021-04-01           20.0    100.0                     5.0       100.0
91  2021-04-02           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
92  2021-04-03           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
93  2021-04-04           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
94  2021-04-05           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
95  2021-04-06           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
96  2021-04-07           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
97  2021-04-08           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
98  2021-04-09           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
99  2021-04-10           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
100 2021-04-11           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
101 2021-04-12           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
102 2021-04-13           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
103 2021-04-14           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
104 2021-04-15           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
105 2021-04-16           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
106 2021-04-17           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
107 2021-04-18           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
108 2021-04-19           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
109 2021-04-20           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
110 2021-04-21           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
111 2021-04-22           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
112 2021-04-23           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
113 2021-04-24           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
114 2021-04-25           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
115 2021-04-26           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
116 2021-04-27           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
117 2021-04-28           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
118 2021-04-29           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
119 2021-04-30           20.0      0.0                     0.0         0.0
```

Comment: Your solution works! Although it's still a bit difficult for me to grasp immediately (I'm sure it'll sink in after I've applied this approach to a couple more solutions), I learned how to use `yield` from your answer. Thank you!